# Welche Eselsbrücken gibt es, um „dass“ und „das“ auseinander zu halten?

Tags: pronoun, conjunction, mnemonic

Die Wörter *das* und *dass* klingen gleich, haben aber völlig unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

Welche Tricks/Eselsbrücken gibt es, um im Schreibfluss rauszufinden, ob man *das* oder *dass* verwenden sollte?

Comment: "Dass" ist von seiner Bedeutung her ursprünglich ein Demonstrativpronomen, welches sich ethymologisch in den nachfolgenden Teilsatz verschoben hat. Man kann es wieder zurück in den ersten Teilsatz verschieben und es wird dann wieder zum normalen "das". Aus "Ich weiß, dass du recht hast" wird dann "Ich weiß das, du hast recht". (siehe: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=dass )

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Das* wird (wie *die* und *der* auch) benutzt, wenn man sich auf ein Subjekt bezieht, welches im Satz bereits erwähnt wurde, meistens also Sachen oder Dinge.

- Wir stiegen in das Flugzeug ein, **das** uns nach Mallorca bringt (Weil: **das** Flugzeug)
- Er leiht mir seinen Rasenmäher, **der** schon sehr alt ist (Weil: **der** Rasenmäher)
- Wir haben eine Katze, **die** nur Blödsinn macht (Weil: **die** Katze)

Man merkt es auch gut daran, dass (!) man alle diese Wörter durch **welche(r/s)** ersetzen kann und der Satz immer noch korrekt ist.

*Dass* hingegen wird benutzt, um Folgerungen auszudrücken oder allgemein Sätze zu verbinden.

- Ich weiß genau, **dass** du mein Auto geklaut hast
- Er sagte mir, **dass** er gleich kommt
- Wir müssen aufpassen, **dass** uns keiner zuvor kommt

Diese Sätze ergeben, wenn man **dass** durch **welche(r/s)** ersetzt, keinen Sinn mehr, da kein Bezugswort existiert.

Ein schönes Beispiel ist auch folgender Satz, der tatsächlich korrektes Deutsch ist.

> Ich wusste doch, dass das das *Dass* ist, das man mit zwei *s* schreibt.

Um es sich zu merken, ist, denke ich, am einfachsten:

> Kann man es durch welche(r/s) ersetzen: Ein *s*. Sonst zwei.

Comment: Oder, nach gutaer alter Sitte ß

Comment: Die eigentliche Eselsbrücke ist wohl der Hinweis auf die Ersetzung durch welches/dieses/jenes. »Ich wusste doch, dass **es** **jenes** Das ist, **welches** man mit zwei "s" schreibt.«

Answer (score 30):

Der Klassiker, den man in der Schule lernt, ist das Wort durch „dieses“ o.ä. zu ersetzen. Wenn der der Satz immer noch (fast) das gleiche bedeutet, dann war’s nur *ein* „s“:

> Ich glaube, dieses du noch viel lernen must.

Völlig sinnfrei, also Doppel-*s*.

> Ich glaube, dieses haben wir gestern in der Schule gelernt.

Holprig, aber richtig – nur ein *s*.

Comment: +1 fürs lustige Beispiel. Ich muss sagen, dass mich der erste Satz ("Ich glaube, dieses du noch viel lernen must") sehr an Yoda erinnert hat. :)

Comment: @MarkusSchwalbe _Viel zu lernen du noch hast_ wäre ein Satz von Yoda. ;)

Comment: @Octavian, ist schon klar^^ Es hat mich ja auch nur daran erinnert.

Answer (score 16):

„Wir haben heute in der Schule gelernt, dass das ‚Das‘ mit einem *S* geschrieben wird, wenn man es durch ‚dieses‘, ‚jenes‘ oder ‚welches‘ ersetzen kann.“

Essenz des Merksatzes ist, dass man es mit einem S schreibt, eben genau wenn man es durch eines der Wörter ersetzen kann. Denn dann bezieht sich das „das“ auf das Subjekt, nicht aber auf die Satzstruktur.

> Wir haben heute in der Schule gelernt, dass dieses ‚Das‘ …

Oder ein anderes Beispiel:

> - Das Auto, das grün ist
> - Das Auto, welches grün ist.

Answer (score 12):

Wenn man es mit *welches* oder *jenes* ersetzen kann, wird es mit nur einem *s* geschrieben.

In Reimform:

> Das s im *das*, es bleibt allein,
>   passt *dieses, jenes, welches* rein.

Comment: @mru siehe Merksatz unten :)

Comment: Ups, den hab ich doch glatt überlesen, sorry ;)

Answer (score 5):

Kann man das Wort durch *dieses*, *jenes* oder *welches* ersetzen, wird *das* mit einem *s* verwendet. In jedem anderen Fall ist es *dass*.

Answer (score 3):

1. In vielen österreichischen Dialekten spricht man die beiden Wörter verschieden aus (das wurde in der Schule nicht genutzt, weil der Dialekt ja ganz pfui ist), deshalb ist es für Muttersprachler eine gute Idee zu überprüfen, ob ihr Dialekt das Problem löst.
2. Stell dir vor, dass du die entsprechende Phrase nicht ganz verstanden hast. Wie würdest du nachfragen?

Das Haus, das Verrückte macht, kommt in diesem Asterixfilm vor.

Wie bitte? **Welches** Haus?

Der Nebensatz erklärt hier das Haus näher.

Ich verstehe nicht, dass du dir so einen dummen Film ansiehst.

**Was** verstehst du nicht?

Der Nebensatz ist hier ein Objekt des Wortes "verstehen".

> 1. In many Austrian dialects the two words are pronounced differently (and this fact was not taught in school because the dialect was discouraged in school), so for German native speakers I suggest to check first if their local dialect helps.
> 2. Imagine that you did not fully understand the das/dass subphrase. How would you ask about it?

Comment: "Das Haus, das Verrückte macht?" Was soll das bedeuten? Stellt das Haus Verrückte her?

Comment: @teylyn: Ja, es gibt einen Asterixfilm, in dem ein haus vorkommt, das Verrückte "herstellt" - eine Behörde. Ungeschickt gewähltes Beispiel.

Comment: Das muss der einzige Asterix sein, den meine Kinder mir noch nicht vorgelesen haben. Kann mir jemand den Titel nennen? Das wird eine Bereicherung ... :)

Comment: @teylyn: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_erobert_Rom

Comment: Der österreichische und auch der bayrische Dialekt sind in diesem Fall wirklich hilfreich. Wobei mir selbst nicht ganz klar ist, warum man beim Dialektsprechen automatisch das richtige wählt, man aber auf Hochdeutsch trotzdem Probleme damit hat.

Comment: +1 für Asterix ;-) @teylyn Das kommt nur in einem der Filme vor, in den Asterix-Comics taucht das nirgendwo auf.

Comment: Auch Schwäbisch ist hilfreich: *des* Haus, *des* Verrückte macht; I hab gehört, *dasch* du da warsch.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin kein Muttersprachler, deswegen bräuchte ich Regeln, um "das/dass" zu unterscheiden. Ich nutze vier Kategorien von "das/dass" dafür.

Not all instances of "das" can be replaced by "die" and "der", so replacement rules do not always work.

First, there are "das", "der", and "die" in a mention of someone or something by their class as in "*das* Kind" and "*das* Buch". This "das" is always written with a single "s".

Secondly, there is "das" as a mention of someone or something that is not yet classified nor named as in "*das* ist Daniel" and "*das* ist ein Tisch". There is also "das", "der", and "die" as a mention of something that is already classified as in "*das* ist ein tolles Buch" and "*der* ist ein toller Film". And there is "das" as a mention of an event as in "*das* habe ich nicht erwartet". All of these "das" are written with a single "s".

Thirdly, there are "das", "der", and "die" in relative clauses that restrict classified things as in "das Buch, *das* ich ausgeliehen habe" and "der Tisch, *den* ich gekauft habe". This "das" is also written with a single "s". However, whenever relative clauses restrict ideas and locutions such as "die Aussage, *dass* niemand zum Markt gekommen ist, stimmt einfach nicht", "dass" is written with double "ss".

Finally, there are "dass" and "so dass" among others that are used to bind clauses as in "ich wusste nicht, *dass* niemand zum Markt gekommen ist" and "es hat so stark geregnet, *dass* niemand zum Markt gekommen ist". These are always written with double "ss".

Comment: Der erste Satz leuchtet mir nicht ganz ein. Weil das Englische *nicht* meine Muttersprache ist, habe ich keine Probleme, *their*, *there* und *they're* auseinanderzuhalten.

Comment: Genau so ist es. Ich habe erkannt, dass mein Französisch langsam besser wird, als ich zum erstenmal ein homophones Partizip statt einem Infinitiv getippt habe.

Answer (score 2):

Inhaltlich nichts neues, aber da explizit nach Eselsbrücken gefragt war, hier noch zwei gereimte Merksätze:

> Das *s* im *das*,
>   es bleibt allein,
>   passt *dieses*, *jenes*,
>   *welches* rein.

[z. B. hier](http://online-lernen.levrai.de/deutsch-uebungen/rechtschreibung_5_7/16_deutsch_uebungen_das_dass/0_das_oder_dass_regeln.htm) (mit einer Reihe von Übungen dazu)

> Das „s“ in „das“ muss einsam bleiben,
>   kannst du auch „dieses“ oder „welches“ schreiben!

[z. B. hier](http://kommunikationsabc.de/2011/10/27/eselsbruecken-fuer-die-deutsche-rechtschreibung/) (mit weiteren Eselsbrücken)

Comment: Oops - habe gerade erst gesehen, daß der erste der beiden Reime schon längst [von splattne gepostet wurde](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/141/9091). Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

"das" ist der Artikel (English the) und "dass" eine Konjunktion (English that + clause). "Das" ist auch Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: Als Relativpronomen leitet *das* Nebensätze ein. Dadurch geht die Unterscheidungsmöglichkeit »satzeinleitendes Wort« verloren. Außerdem verlangt diese Antwort die Kenntnis grammatikalischer Begriffe um die Wörter zu unterscheiden. – 1

Answer (score 0):

"Das" bestimmt ein Subjekt, ist also ein bestimmter Artikel. "Dass" leitet einen Objektsatz ein (meist Nebensatz, durch Komma getrennt). Wenn man "Was" fragen kann, wird "dass" mit Doppel-S geschrieben. Wenn der Nebensatz eine nähere Erläuterung des Subjekts ist, wird "das" mit nur einem S geschrieben (adjektivischer Nebensatz).
Bsp. für 2: Das grüne Auto. (Adjektiv "grün") kann auch als
            'Das Auto, das grün ist.' ausgedrückt werden.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Nimm dir die Zeit für eine [tour] der Seite und schaue bei Unklarheiten im [help] nach. Leider gibt deine Antwort einerseits wenig neues, andererseits ist sie auch in Teilen falsch. Deswegen –1. Ich hoffe, dass du trotzdem bei uns bleibst um Fragen zu stellen und zu beantworten.